# Javac cannot find symbol for job class

Tags: java, hadoop

My execution file is:

```
package hadoop; 

import java.util.*; 

import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.IOException; 

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path; 
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*; 
import javax.lang.model.util.Elements;
public class ProcessUnits 
{ 
   //Mapper class 
   public static class E_EMapper extends MapReduceBase implements 
   Mapper<LongWritable ,/*Input key Type */ 
   Text,                /*Input value Type*/ 
   Text,                /*Output key Type*/ 
   IntWritable>        /*Output value Type*/ 
   { 

      //Map function 
      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, 
      OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output,   
      Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
      { 
         String line = value.toString(); 
         String lasttoken = null; 
         StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(line,"\t"); 
         String year = s.nextToken(); 

         while(s.hasMoreTokens())
            {
               lasttoken=s.nextToken();
            } 

         int avgprice = Integer.parseInt(lasttoken); 
         output.collect(new Text(year), new IntWritable(avgprice)); 
      } 
   } 


   //Reducer class 
   public static class E_EReduce extends MapReduceBase implements 
   Reducer< Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable > 
   {  

      //Reduce function 
      public void reduce( Text key, Iterator <IntWritable> values, 
         OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
         { 
            int maxavg=30; 
            int val=Integer.MIN_VALUE; 

            while (values.hasNext()) 
            { 
               if((val=values.next().get())>maxavg) 
               { 
                  output.collect(key, new IntWritable(val)); 
               } 
            } 

         } 
   }  


   //Main function 
   public static void main(String args[])throws Exception 
   { 
      JobConf conf = new JobConf(Eleunits.class); 

      conf.setJobName("max_eletricityunits"); 
      conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class); 
      conf.setMapperClass(E_EMapper.class); 
      conf.setCombinerClass(E_EReduce.class); 
      conf.setReducerClass(E_EReduce.class); 
      conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class); 
      conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class); 

      FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0])); 
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1])); 

      JobClient.runJob(conf); 
   } 
}
```

When I compile it with:

javac -classpath /home/javier/entrada/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar -d /home/javier/units /home/javier/entrada/ProcessUnits.java

I have the following error:

```
javac -classpath /home/javier/entrada/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar -d /home/javier/units /home/javier/entrada/ProcessUnits.java
/home/javier/entrada/ProcessUnits.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
      JobConf conf = new JobConf(Eleunits.class); 
                                 ^
  symbol:   class Eleunits
  location: class ProcessUnits
1 error
```

My version of hadoop is 2.9.2 and my version of java is 1.8.0_191

When I open it with eclipse and look at it, I do not find the import of Eleunits.class

Comment: My library is hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar

Comment: it's not a hadoop question, but a java one.. what is "Eleunits"? it is not imported in your code

Comment: Class name is ProcessUnits not Eleunits . Replace Eleunits.class with ProcessUnits.class

Answer (score 1):

> My version of hadoop is 2.9.2 and my version of java is 1.8.0_191

First off, `hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar` was built way before Hadoop 2.9.2 was even a thought, so you're going to need a new JAR

> When I open it with eclipse and look at it, I do not find the import of Eleunits.class

Not clear why you weren't using Eclipse the whole time! Even not using Maven or Gradle to grab the correct library versions for Hadoop is scary to me... But Eclipse probably isn't lying. You've only shown one class, and that class is not called `Eleunits`, and I'm not sure how you got that value other than copied from elsewhere

In addition, the main class should `extends Configured implements Tool` , as you'll find in other MapReduce examples